# weird rate problem that I can't solve

Tags: physics

Two teams compete in a relay race, they're composed of 4 members, each of whom runs 100 meters. All of the members of team B runs at $b$ meters per second (mps). The first 3 members of team A can only run at 5$b$/6 (mps) while the 4th member runs at $a$ mps. Find $a$/$b$ if the race is a tie.

Comment: You know time and distance have to be the same.  What have you tried?

Comment: What have you tried? You should have used: time = distance / speed.

Comment: d/r = d/r since it's a tie where d is the same 100m left with 1/r = 1/r team B combined rate = 4b while team A combined rate = 3* (5b/6) + a , solving this I get a/b = 3/2

Answer (score 4):

The total time it takes team A to run the race is $$T_A=\frac{300 \text{ m}}{5b/6 \text{ ms}^{-1}}+\frac{100\text{ m}}{a \text{ ms}^{-1}}$$
The time it takes team B to run the race is $$T_B=\frac{400\text{ m}}{b\text{ ms}^{-1}}$$
Therefore,
 $$T_A=T_B \implies \frac{a}{b}=\frac{5}{2}$$
EDIT: My workings - 
$$\frac{300}{5b/6} + \frac{100}{a} = \frac{400}{b}$$
$$\frac{18}{5b} + \frac{1}{a} = \frac{4}{b}$$
$$\frac{18}{b} + \frac{5}{a}=\frac{20}{b}$$
$$\frac{2}{b}=\frac{5}{a}$$ 
It's straightforward from here.

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in my previous post. $a/b =1/6$ is **wrong**. The above answer is now correct.

Comment: It's important to note that the $\implies$ conceals some simplification.

Comment: Ok, I'll add my workings.

Comment: "The team is composed of 4 members, each of whom runs 100 meters."

Comment: @K. defaoite. You're right. It makes more practical sense, too. I'll delete my comment.

Comment: Each of them runs 100m so why isn't it correct to write that the time team B takes is = 4 * (100/b) and team A = 3 * (100/5b/6) + 100/a ? Please help me understand

Comment: @LazyJoeShow This is equivalent to what I wrote. All I did was multiply the 3 and the 4 into the fractions you wrote above.

Comment: Oh right sorry I meant 300/3(5b/6) since there are 3 members with that speed and 400/4(b) since there are 4 members , thanks for taking the time to explain!

Comment: What I've done is let d/r = d/r since it's a tie where d is the same 100m left with 1/r = 1/r team B combined rate = 4b while team A combined rate = 3* (5b/6) + a , solving this I get a/b = 3/2 . @K.defaoite please tell me whats wrong I appreciate it

Comment: Just because the race is a tie doesn't mean both teams have to run the last 100 meters in the same amount of time. I could let Usain Bolt start running a 100 meter race and then wait till he's 0.0000035 meters from the finish line and then shine a beam of light at the start and it would still be a tie.

Comment: If each of team B needs to cover 100m so total distance will be 400m and there are 4 members, so shouldn't the time be 400/4b? I think you haven't clarified my question enough or I'm just too dumb?

Comment: Each member of team B runs 100 meters at a rate of $b$ meters per second. So the time it takes one member to run his portion is $\frac{100}{b}\text{s}$. If the team has $4$ members, then this needs to be repeated $4$ times, so the total time is $4\times \frac{100}{b}\text{s}=\frac{400}{b}\text{s}$, not $\frac{400}{4b}\text{s}$.

Answer (score 1):

The total time for the tie race is

$$ \frac Sb = \frac {\frac {3S}4}{\frac56b}+ \frac{\frac S4}a
$$

where $S$ is the total distance that cancels. Solve to obtain $\frac ab = \frac52$.

Comment: Quite elegant :)